# SQL Sorting by Value, but keeping data from the same user together

Tags: sql-server

I have a `User` table with `ID` and `Value` columns.
General sorting is by `Value DESC`, but if the user already exist I'd like to output same user under each other. Hopefully it makes sense (see required output below):

*Table:*

```
User      Value
1111      5000
2222      6000  
3333      4000  
1111      1000
```

*Output:*

```
User   Value
2222   6000
1111   5000
1111   1000
3333   4000
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is run a pre-query which determines the maximum value for each user. This max value can then be used to then control the ordering from the final query. I've used a CTE to do the max value pre-query, which can then be used to join back into the original table for the final ordering.

```
WITH MaxUserPrice AS
(
  SELECT [User], MAX([Value]) AS MaxValue
  FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY [User]
)
SELECT mt.[User], mt.[Value]
FROM MYTABLE mt INNER JOIN MaxUserPrice mup ON mt.[User] = mup.[User]
ORDER BY mup.MaxValue DESC, mt.[User], mt.[Value] DESC;
```

There's a [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d0451/5)

With notes:

- We need to keep `[User]` as a second ordering criterion in the final query, since if there's a tie on the maximum value, then I assume you want to keep the user data together.
- And `Value DESC` must also be in the order, since we need to retain the value ordering within the same user.